# tsconfig.json complaining about relative path

Tags: typescript

I have a tsconfig.json file structured in this way.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "react-native",
        "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "components/*": ["./app/components"],
            "components/*/*": ["./app/components/*/index"],
            "services/*": ["./app/services"],
            "app/*": ["./app"],
            "navigation/*": ["./app/navigation"],
            "theme/*": ["./app/theme/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

I have a problem with this line:

```
"components/*/*": ["./app/components/*/index"],
```

TS is complaining about the fact that:

```
Pattern 'components/*/*' can have at most one '*' character.
```

This is causing me an infinity of issues with my imports and I am quite stuck at the moment, I cannot find anyone that had the same issue.
Can someone help me get out of this rabbit hole?